# querySelectorAll and :first child

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I'm trying to get a list of only the first links per row in one wikipedia table with querySelectorAll but I am not sure why the :first-child selector is not working. I know there is other ways to do it but I want to know if there is a solution to this specific problem with the querySelectorAll function.

see my attemps below the html:

```
<table class='wikitable'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="" title="">John doe</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="" title="">other link</a>
    </td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="" title="">Mary Jane</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="" title="">another link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My Code:

```
let list = document.querySelectorAll(('.wikitable tr:first-child td:first-child a'));
```

the previous code is just returning a node with one element:

```
<a href="" title="">John doe</a>
```

Instead a list:

```
<a href="" title="">John doe</a>
<a href="" title="">Mary Jane</a>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct selector should be

```
".wikitable tr td:first-child a"
```

`tr:first-child` means “the `tr` *which is* the first child”. This only applies to

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="" title="">John doe</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="" title="">other link</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

In `'.wikitable tr:first-child td:first-child a'`, `tr:first-child` will select only `tr` elements that are a first child (i.e. it only selects the first `tr`).

`'.wikitable tr td:first-child a'` will go to each row in the '.wikitable' table and select any `a` anchors in the first cell (presumably there will be only one, but technically there can be more).

Comment: It might be a matter of taste but  `'.wikitable > tr > td:first-child > a'` is still more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

you need to iterate over all the rows so selector will be

```
document.querySelectorAll(('.wikitable tr td:first-child a'));
```

using **tr:first-child**  will only select the first row.

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll(('.wikitable tr td:first-child a')); 

console.log(list);
```

```html
<table class='wikitable'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="" title="">John doe</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="" title="">other link</a>
    </td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="" title="">Mary Jane</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="" title="">another link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```